Forward price arbitrage
To price a forward on a stock we usually use arbitrage to find that the price of the forward is the price of the stock compounded by the risk free rate.
I don't have the data to try things, so was wondering from people that worked in the industry if this is actually what we observe in the market?
Basically I am wondering if hedge-funds actually makes money using this arbitrage. Since the stock price moves but also the risk free rate, so I would except the number of dislocations to happen a lot.
Hence my question, are there a lot of hedge-funds that actually have strategies that exploits these arbitrage, and is the formula for the price of the forward actually close to the price we observe in the market?

A couple of years back there were some arbitrage possibilities in equity forwards due to funding dislocations. I actually did observe it and could have traded it. Not sure if it still exists. Some background on this here: https://www.globalvolatilitysummit.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/05/A-New-Normal-in-Equity-Repo-BNP-Paribas.pdf
